# Поиск в глубину для матрицы

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Здравствуйте. У меня есть матрица вида:

```
matrix = [
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
 ];
```

Мне надо найти путь от точки start до точки end. Двигаться можно только по ячейкам, которые содержат 0.

```
var start = [0,4];
 var end = [4,0];
```

Передвигаться я могу только в четырех направлениях. Вверх, вниз, лево, право. Направления записаны у меня в массиве.

```
var direction = [[1,0], [0,1], [-1, 0], [0,-1]];
```

Я вроде как поняла алгоритм поиска вглубь. Но у меня проблема именно с направлениями движения.
Вот то как поняла я:
1) устанавливаем ячейку в координаты старта.
2) начинаем сдвигать ячейку по массиву направлений.
3) если данное направление мне не подходит(ячейка равна единице или ячейки не существует, или индексы ячейки больше размерности матрицы, или меньше нуля) возвращаюсь обратно и перехожу на новое направление.
4) если ячейка мне походит, устанавливаю текущую ячейку в нее и вызываю функцию снова.

Только вот проблема в том, как мне проверить, а не равна ли соседняя ячейка значению end? Просто дописать еще один if?

Вообщем, я не совсем понимаю, как правильно реализовать сам алгоритм. Возможно как раз алгоритм я не совсем и поняла. Буду рада любой помощи.

Comment: Вроде в вопросе всё верно и подробно описано...

Comment: @Qwertiy, вот только с реализацией у меня не получается. Вроде логика и правильная, а оно не работает.

Comment: @kittycat_13 Написал Вам приблизительно как это может выглядеть. Может можно сделать это проще или как-то по-другому... [собственно ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/po5dL9t1/1/)

Comment: @IgorLut, спасибо большое)

Comment: @IgorLut, я написала свой вариант функции, но у меня есть несколько проблем. Во первых - при запуске скрипта мне выдается ошибка, что стек переполнен(Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded) в строке, где я объявляю переменную dimension. И второе - как мне реализовать условие, что если нет пути куда двигаться. У меня как-то косо все получилось. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.     https://jsfiddle.net/LsLLetjv/

Comment: @kittycat_13 Для начала, скажите, зачем Вам direction ? На сколько я понимаю, функция сама должна найти путь к end? А тут Вы сами задаете ей куда идти...

Comment: @IgorLut, просто мне надо реализовать поиск в глубину по 4-м ячейкам(вниз, вправо, лево, вверх) и по 8-ми(вниз, вниз-вправо, вниз-лево, лево, вверх-право, вверх-лево, вверх, вправо). Вот я и подумала, что надо сразу задать направления движения. В добавок, каждое направление, может иметь определенный приоритет. Допустим, у меня свободно и левое направление и право. Так вот, я выберу то направление, приоритет которого будет выше.

Comment: @kittycat_13 Теряется весь смысл самой функции тогда. Получается, что Вы находите путь вместо функции.. Вы представьте, что не знаете, что в matrix. Мой вариант это на 70% решение Ваших задач. Вам нужно разобраться, как работает рекурсия и просто доделать задачу. По 8-ми будет точно так же, просто добавите по аналогии переменные leftDown и т.д.

Comment: @IgorLut, спасибо. Просто у меня в голове не укладывается как может функция сама двигать ячейку. Скажите еще, пожалуйста, а почему Ваш вариант не может найти другой путь? Я как понимаю, в Вашем варианте если есть путь вниз, она будет двигаться вниз независимо от того, есть ли путь вбок или вверх.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65956/discussion-between-kittycat-13-and-igor-lut).

Comment: Если ещё актуально, хочу сказать, что от direction и правда нет пользы. Функция не должна сдвигать ячейку. Функция должна просто знать нужные координаты на рассмотрения. Для этого Вы передавайте функции i и j как аргумент. Потом, при вызове рекурсии, передавайте ей изменённые i и j.

Comment: Также у вас может быть переполнение стека, так как рекурсия входит сама в себя до бесконечности. К примеру, сначала из i, j в i+1, j. А потом опять в i, j. Причём вы не вернулись, вы просто сделали ещё один рекурсивный вызов. Мощности компьютеров ограничены, поэтому слишком много рекурсивных вызовов не может быть. Чтобы не было таких казусов с петлями, просто помечайте все клетки, в которые вошли. Если вы вошли в клетку, больше не входите. Это ещё одно небольшое условие для if.

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко, спасибо. Но мне все еще не ясно, что делать, если нужен откат действия и смена маршрута. Если мне действительно нужен возврат на предыдущую позицию и смена маршрута.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DFS у вас вероятно рекурсивный, поэтому пример сделаю для него. Для нерекурсивного DFS логика будет похожей.

Вы говорите, нужно дойти от start до end.
Так вот, вовсе не обязательно проверять является ли эта соседняя клетка конечной.

Проще сделать немного по-другому:

1. Проверяем в конце ли мы, если да, то завершаем рекурсию и делаем с этими данными что Вам нужно. Если нет, продолжаем.
2. Проверяем соседние клетки, и если можем войти в них, входим рекурсивно.

Таким образом, каждая клетка в которую вы войдёте, будет проверена.
Также вы избавляетесь от лишних проверок.

Comment: А суть самого алгоритма, как вы скорее всего и сами поняли, в рекурсивном входе в каждую подходящую вершину, чтобы в итоге по шажкам прийти в конечную :)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Только один вопрос. В первом пункте мы делаем проверку на то, находимся ли мы в ячеек до которой надо дойти, то есть до end?

Comment: И еще вопрос, если можно) По второму пункту. У меня например есть две соседние клетки в которые я могу зайти. Мне заходить по очереди в обе?

Comment: Да. Именно так. Вы ставите несколько if для всех соседей (i ± 1, j±1) и проверяете, можно ли зайти в каждую из них. Если у вас получится несколько таких клеток, то вы сначала войдёте в одну из них, а потом, через некоторое время, рекурсия вернётся обратно, после чего войдёт в другую :-)

Comment: А если у меня такая ситуация. Допустим я стою на ячейке. Перехожу на соседнюю ячейку. Делаю осмотр всех ближайших ячеек, но ни одна из них не подходит. Как мне сделать откат на предыдущую ячейку и поменять направление движения?

Comment: Как уже писал, в большинстве, если не всех, языках программирования, когда вы входите из рекурсивного вложения А в рекурсивное вложение B, когда B отрабатывает своё, вы опять возвращаетесь в A. Причём аргументы и переменные А сохраняются.

Comment: Представьте это в виде стека. Вы вызываете А. В стеке создаётся новая ячейка. Из A вы входите в Б, и создаётся вторая ячейка. В ячейке А свои данные -- в ячейке Б свои. Когда Б отрабатывает и завершается, самый верхний элемент стека сносится, и вы возвращаетесь в А в то место, откуда вызывали Б.

Comment: Мне все равно не понятно. Если у нас есть запрет на посещение ячейки, в которой мы уже были, но мне надо туда попасть, то что же делать? Это тупик.

Comment: Никак не тупик. Вы запрещаете входить в уже использованную ячейку чисто условно. Когда вы выбираете куда пойти, вы ставите соответствующее условие. Тут же вы выходите обратно в А без условий. Если вы вышли из Б, туда вам больше точно ничего не понадобится. Скорее всего, останутся ещё клетки, в которые вы и войдёте. Когда вы не сможете никуда идти, то либо вокруг вас стены, либо вы везде были и всё проверили.